# ¿Por qué aparece la advertencia "warning: [!] Your project does not explicitly specify the CocoaPods master specs repo." con iOS con Genexus 17 U4?

Tags: ios, genexus, cocoapods

Al generar aplicación iOS con Genexus 17 Upgrade 4 aparece la siguiente advertencia:

warning: [!] Your project does not explicitly specify the CocoaPods master specs repo. Since CDN is now used as the default, you may safely remove it from your repos directory via `pod repo remove master`. To suppress this warning please add `warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo => false` to your Podfile.

Answer (score 0):

Eso es un tema de configuración de la Mac, que quedó un repositorio `master` que ya no es necesario...

Tienes que ejecutar el comando que te dice en el mensaje:

```sh
pod repo remove master
```